# Modal window does not open to confirm deletion, js

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to integrate into my site in bootstrap 5, a modal window to confirm the deletions, but for some reason the modal sale is not shown and therefore the link is not executed. What is wrong? Maybe you know something better for it... Thank you

This is link href

```
<a href="index.php?del=1" data-confirm='¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar el elemento seleccionado?'><button class="btn btn-outline-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm" type="button"><span class="btn-label"><i class="bi bi-trash3"></i></span>Eliminar</button></a>
```

Js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(!$('#confirm-delete').length){

        
        $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header bg-danger text-white">ELIMINAR REGISTRO<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div><div class="modal-body">¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar el elemento seleccionado?</div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button><a class="btn btn-danger text-white" id="dataComfirmOK">Borrar cliente</a></div></div></div></div>');
    }
    $('#dataComfirmOK').attr('href', href);
    $('#confirm-delete').modal({show: true});
    return false;
 });
});
```

edit, I've been doing no tests and the part that doesn't work is .append

edit again: Im solved

Edit again, in case someone has the same problem, I have changed this part of the code

```
$('#confirm-delete').modal({show: true});
```

to

```
$("#confirm-delete").modal("show");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, if you change

```
$('#confirm-delete').modal({
    show: true
});
```

to

```
$('#confirm-delete').modal('show');
```

then it should trigger showing the modal. Tested on the latest Bootstrap (v5.2).

Comment: not work....
edit, I've been doing no tests and the part that doesn't work is .append

Answer (score 0):

Your link was going to the `href` it has. You should cancel that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a[data-confirm]').click(function(ev) {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (!$('#confirm-delete').length) {


      $('body').append('<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header bg-danger text-white">ELIMINAR REGISTRO<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div><div class="modal-body">¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar el elemento seleccionado?</div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button><a class="btn btn-danger text-white" id="dataComfirmOK">Borrar cliente</a></div></div></div></div>');
    }
    $('#dataComfirmOK').attr('href', href);
    $('#confirm-delete').modal({
      show: true
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<a href="index.php?del=1" data-confirm='¿Está seguro de que desea eliminar el elemento seleccionado?' onclick="return false">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-danger waves-effect waves-light btn-sm" type="button">
    <span class="btn-label"><i class="bi bi-trash3"></i></span>
    Eliminar
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work either. is there any other method?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: modal window is not displayed

Comment: Try to adapt this working snippet to your needs.